# Как получить доступ к текущей таблице после её добавления?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

У меня есть таблица `tb_questions` после добавлении в нее новой записи, мне нужно моментально добавить в `tb_recipients` **id**  данной записи, то есть в `tb_recipients` есть столбец **id_questions** после добавлении новой записи в `tb_questions` **id** этого последнего **question** должен добавиться в `tb_recipients`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сразу же после добавления записи вызывайте:

Mysql:

```
$last_id = mysql_insert_id($conn);
```

Mysqli:

```
$last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
```

PDO:

```
$last_id = $conn->lastInsertId();
```